# Using Debian tools for building g++

Tags: g++, debian, configure, apt-get

I would like to rebuild g++ with my own specific settings.

Here is what I did so far:

```
sudo aptitude install build-dep g++-4.2
mkdir trial && cd trial
apt-get source g++-4.2
```

Now I want to configure my specific settings. For g++ this is normally done by e.g.

```
sh configure --prefix=/home/voku/non-productive
```

But unfortunately I cannot find a `configure` or `configure.ac` script inside the download directory.

What I am actually looking for is a way to say:

- get the source
- apply all the needed patches
- become `ready to build` - but do not build

Are there additional steps that I need to get the `configure` script?

**EDIT**:
Probably I could run one of the tools that actually create the .deb package for g++.

Afterwards - that's what I assume - there will be the needed configure script.

But that sounds awful:

- build the g++ .deb package
- cleanup the whole stuff again
- then use the generated configure script with my own options
- then build again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of Debian's source packages are special packages that build .deb files, which should be built using dpkg-buildpackage.  Cf. [Apt Howto: Working with source packages](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-sourcehandling.en.html).

Comment: @Charles: yes - you are right. But internally a tool like `dpkg-buildpackage` also runs `configure` somewhere during the .deb package build process.<br>Probably I could run one of the tools that actually create the .deb package for g++. Afterwards - that's what I assume - there will be the needed configure  script.<br>But that sounds awful: build the package, then clean up the stuff again. Then configure with my own option. Then build again.

Comment: @Vokuhila: Maybe there is something worth looking at in the rules file: cf. http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/ch-dreq.en.html#s-rules

Answer (score 1):

As always, read the `INSTALL` file to learn what steps you must take in order to build the code.

Comment: where did you find the `INSTALL` file? I don't have it, neither `README`, `BUILD` nor something that sounds similar.